# Webscraping wikipedia infoboxes using beautiful beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to extract the following information from country information from Wikipedia using Beautiful Soup:

- Political system
- President
- Vice President
- Area

e.g.
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China

I want

| Political System | Unitary Marxist–Leninist one-party socialist republic |
| --- | --- |
| President | Xi Jinping |
| Premier | Li Qiang |
| Area | 9,596,961 km2 |

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India

I want

| Political System | Federal parliamentary constitutional republic |
| --- | --- |
| President | Droupadi Murmu |
| Vice President | Jagdeep Dhankhar |
| Area | 3,287,263 km2 |

Ideally I would pass a list of all countries using

```
f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{country}'
```

and iterate through the list to capture these info from different countries.

The issue encountered is that:

1. After the political system, the name president/vice president is not identical for every country [in china's case it is President/Premier], ideally I would like to capture the first 2 entries along with their header name
2. I am not able to capture the value of "Total", which stores the value of area in the html

Comment: There's really no reason to web-scape Wikipedia! All of its content is available via APIs. And what you're looking for specifically is even part of [Wikidata](https://wikidata.org/) in a structured form, with [various ways to access the data](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access). For example [here's China](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q148).

Answer (score 2):

I get all text in the table you can crawl it with re.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

countries = ['China', 'USA', 'Azerbaijan']

df = pd.DataFrame(countries,columns=['countries'])
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Whoama'
}
for a in df.countries:
    url = f'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{a}'
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    sp = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(sp.select_one('table.infobox.ib-country.vcard').text)


# If you want to crawl government:
print(sp.select_one('tbody').text.split('Government')[-1].split('Legislature')[0])

#Legislature:
print(sp.select_one('tbody').text.split('Legislature')[-1].split('Area')[0])
```

Comment: I recommend crawl this like that then parse it for what you want.

Comment: I have been able to implement it by first finding the "gorvenment" or "area" in list of all "tr" and then to find next "tr" after them using .find_next_sibling(). this way the next item can have any label, but we are sure to get the correct one.